# Merge multiple optimization paths in mlr

Tags: mlr

Is it possible to merge the results of two tuning processes with the same parameter set? I am currently using the function `addOptPathEl` in a loop, but I wonder if there is something to do it faster.

Thanks!
Víctor

Comment: Would at be an option to convert both to a `data.frame` with `as.data.frame(op)` and then rbinding them?

Comment: It is! But I lose the classes "OptPath" and "OptPathDF". I am not sure if that is important for the framework.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Afterwards you won't be able to use the objects with most mlr functions. But most evaluations can be done on the data.frame pretty easily.

Comment: Mainly I want to plot the results of the combined paths. But finally I did that by using ggplot2 with the merged data frame. The main reason of my question was pure curiosity about that functionality in mlr. I consider it as solved. Thanks!!!